# Cayley nomenclature

Tags: gr.group-theory, soft-question

Suppose I have a finitely generated group $G$ acting on a set $X,$ and we make a graph, whose vertex set is $X,$ and where we join $x_1$ to $x_2$ by an edge labeled $g_i$ if $g_i(x_1) = x_2.$ What is this called? Is it still a Cayley graph?

Comment: It's the union of complete graphs on orbits... more generally when you only do it for $g$ in a given generating set, it's called Schreier graph (not Cayley graph).

Comment: (Actually this is a labeled graph allowing multiplicities, so in the first case it's a bit more that just the complete graph... it called the action groupoid.)

Comment: @YCor $g_i$ is a generator, not an arbitrary element, so I guess Schreier graph is it...

Comment: It is actually a category, not (only) a graph. It is called [action groupoid](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/action+groupoid).